# Much smaller .so file for identical source code

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk

My Android application (game) uses native C++ code for certain operations. That is, I use the Android NDK. The native C++ code is compiled for *armeabi* only (to the default, *armeabi-v5*).

The last time I built my c++ code into `nativestuff.so` was a few months ago, in another computer (Windows 7 + cygwin, because cygwin is recommended for compiling with Android NDK).

I just installed the NDK on my current PC (Windows 7), along with the newest cygwin, and rebuilt the c++ code for my app.

To my surprise, it generates an `.so` file of 14KB, while the previous `.so` file was 37KB. Note that the c++ source files *are exactly the same* (they haven't changed for a year), my project is under version control, so I'm 100% sure.

I tested the c++ functionality in the game, and it works exactly as before, without any bugs.

My C++ files use only `cstring.h` and `jni.h` as includes. My `Android.mk` is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativestuff
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nativestuff.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Any idea why the drastic change in `.so` filesize?

(I added the `linux` tag as well to this question, because maybe it's a general thing so I want to make sure that linux gurus also check it.)

Comment: you should never use the NDK under cygwin, there is a dedicated build for windows and having a different binary for different version of your toolchain it's not that rare, also you are not specifying any useful detail like what compiler you are using, what platforms are you targeting, what kind of libraries are you using, etc etc ...

Comment: I installed the NDK version for Windows, and then installed cygwin, because the official Android documentation states that it should be used for building (for calling the ndk-build file). I use the newest Android NDK, downloaded today.

Comment: "For Windows, Cygwin 1.7 or higher is required." Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I am targeting armeabi, thanks for reminding me to mention this. So the .so is for armeabi (the default one, v5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `objdump -x file.so` on both versions. This will list all the [sections](https://lwn.net/Articles/531148/) and their sizes. That should give you a clue as to where the problem lies. (i.e. is there a new .debug section that's 23KB long? Maybe debug mode got enabled.)

If your code sections are radically different, compare the output of `objdump -d file.so`. Maybe your compiler automatically inlined more code, which saved a lot of space.

If another section is new/different, post the output in another SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the previous .so was generated with debugging information.
(compiled with gcc -g option)

Comment: Possible, but even when the original .so is generated with debug info, the version that goes in the apk and onto the device is typically stripped.  Though it's possible a quirk of the old toolchain skipped that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try one thing: use the command size executable-name. That will give you size of the different areas of your executable code. If the previous build is available do the same to that. You may get an idea where the change is.